# css animation doesn't work in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

My code doesnt work in Firefox and I dont know why. Any advices? It works fine in Chrome, IE and Opera. I tried almost all prefixes combinations but still it wont work. Is it possible that something is wrong with my PC or Firefox browser?

```css
.span-accent {
    color: rgb(60, 185, 120);
    -webkit-animation: breath 2s infinite;
    -moz-animation: breath 2s infinite;
    animation: breath 2s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes breath {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    25% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes breath {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    25% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    50% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    75% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@keyframes breath {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    25% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>LAKA</h1>
<h2>architecture that <span class="span-accent">reacts.</span></h2>
```

Comment: `-moz-transform: scale(1);  -webkit-transform: scale(1);` why webkit?

Comment: As suggested by @Morpheus use the right prefix into your keyframes

Comment: `-moz-transform: scale(1); transform: scale(1);` it doesn't work this way either

Comment: Don't know if that will help, but looks like it's a known bug -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes (scroll to the notes section)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok guys, I found it.

Problem is in `<span>` element. For some reason Firefox doesnt animate inline elements.

So what I did is change a `<span>` atribute to `display: inline-block`. 
It just wont work strictly for any `inline` element.

Comment: Looks like my comment helped :)